# Is it possible to access a property of a class using Generics in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, generics, typescript

I have the following class which will be the base for the entities of the application

```
namespace Base {
    export abstract class BaseEntity {
        endpoint: string;
        public abstract getId(): string;
    }
}
```

And the implementation of this class is given as follows:

```
namespace Example {
    export class Account extends Base.BaseEntity {
        accountId?: string;
        name?: string;
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.endpoint = "accounts";
        }

        public getId(): string {
            return this.accountId;
        }
    }
}
```

The objective of this is to be able to obtain the value of the `endpoint` property of each class to know the url of the web method defined in an Api Web.

Here's the example:

```
namespace Base {
    export class BaseService<T extends BaseEntity> {
        private url: string;
        constructor(
            private $q: angular.IQService,
            private $http: angular.IHttpService) {
            this.url = `http://localhost:81/api/${(<BaseEntity>T).endpoint}`; //ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
        }
    }
}
```

But throw the following error on this instruction`${(<BaseEntity>T).endpoint}`:

> //ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How can I access the value of that property dynamically?

**UPDATE**
 I need to start from angular controller:

```
namespace Example {

    class AccountController extends Base.BaseController<Account> {

    }
    angular
        .module("Example")
        .controller("AccountController", AccountController);
}
```

In the controller constructor, pass the BaseService where T is defined from the controller definition

```
namespace Base {
    export class BaseController<T extends Base.BaseEntity> {
        list: Array<T>;
        constructor(
            private baseService: Base.BaseService<T>
        ) {            

        }

        public get(): void {
            this.baseService.get().then(
                list => {
                    this.list = list;
                },
                error => {
                    console.error("Error: ",error);
                }
            )
        }

        public save(entity: T): void {
            this.baseService.save(entity).then(
                resp => {
                    if (resp.completed) {
                        //TODO: code.
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.error("Error: ", error);
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now I understand that 'T' is a type and not a value,
But **how can I achieve the reuse of this code?**
Since I see that I repeat the same code in all my controllers and services, it only changes the entity

Comment: This doesn't even make sense without generics. For any given `T` there's nothing preventing different instances of the same class from having a different `endpoint` property value.

Comment: The generic `T` isn't a value. You need to have an instance of type `T` on which you could just do `instance.endpoint`. How are you creating the instance of `Account` for example?

Comment: Thanks for your comments now I updated my question